# How do I fix an error with dataaspectratio not being finite in Octave?

Tags: octave

I'm writing a simple script that iterates some data and plots the result.  It was working fine.  Then I zoomed in on the plot.  After doing that, every time I try to run it I get the error

> error: set: "dataaspectratio" must be finite

whether I use `plot()` or `pcolor()`.  I found from a search that I can check the data aspect ratio with `daspect()` and the answer is `[4 2 1]` which looks finite to me.  Even if I close and restart this error persists and won't let me plot anything, even a simple thing from the command line.  Or a graph comes up with no y axis.  How can I fix this?

The full error trying to run my file logistic.m is:

> ```
> logistic
> error: set: "dataaspectratio" must be finite
> error: called from
>    __plt__>__plt2vv__ at line 495 column 10
>    __plt__>__plt2__ at line 242 column 14
>    __plt__ at line 107 column 18
>    plot at line 223 column 10
>    logistic at line 8 column 1
> error: set: "dataaspectratio" must be finite
> ```

---

Here's the full script that I used:

```
R=linspace(0,4,100);
for j=1:100
  r=R(j);
  X=linspace(0,1,100);
  for i=1:1000
    X=r*(X-X.*X);
  endfor
  plot(R,X);
  hold on;
endfor
```

---

Just now, after starting Octave again, this problem went away.  A while later it came back. All I did was zoom into a plot that I made. The plot window still comes up the first time, but it's just a horizontal line with no axes. After that, the plot window doesn't even come up.

Comment: Please see [mre], bug reports without a way to reproduce them are not useful. Include the version number of Octave you use.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  I'm using Octave 5.1.0 on Windows.  I added the script to my OP.

Comment: Now the error's back.  All I did was zoom into a plot that I made.  The plot window still comes up the first time, but it's just a horizontal line with no axes.  After that, the plot window doesn't even come up.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but does anyone have a solution?  The errors I'm getting seem like they'd be easy to understand for someone more familiar with Octave.  Why does it say it needs to be finite when it already is?  Is there a generally accepted way to reset this value or do some "master reset" of all of Octave?